# CakePHP : find with conditions on hasMany association

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to filter `find()` results with conditions on an associated model.

I found solutions available for CakePHP 2.x, but I am working with CakePHP 3.x.

I use these models :

- Contacts : `hasMany('Orders')`
- Orders : `belongsTo('Contacts')`

In my ContactsController, I want to display **only contacts that have one or more orders**.

```
public function customers() {
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Orders'],
        'having' => ['Orders']
    ];
    $contacts = $this->paginate($this->Contacts);
    $this->set('contacts', $contacts);
}
```

Of course, it doesn't work, because CakePHP doesn't use joins with 'hasMany' associations, and I get this error :

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Orders' in 'having clause'

But how can I use the conditions to get only contacts that have already orders ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this solution is the best, but it works :
By using a custom `join`, you can count the number of orders by contact, and then use `having` on count_orders.

```
    $contacts = $this->Contacts->find('all', [
        'fields' => [
            'contact_id' => 'Contacts.contact_id',
            // Others fields you need
            'count_orders' => 'COUNT(order_id)'
        ],
        'join' => [
            'table' => 'orders', 
            'type' => 'LEFT', 
            'conditions' => 'orders.contact_id = Contacts.contact_id'
        ],
        'group' => ['Contacts.contact_id'],
        'having' => ['count_orders > 0'] // Remove contacts without orders
    ]);
    $this->set('contacts', $contacts);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['contacts']);
```

Comment: Maybe not the best, but it works ! I used your solution with `paginate()` and I got what I expected : contact list that have already ordered.

Comment: is 'fields' key  the correct to selects fields in 3.0. the book says select()/'select' key method should be used for that. i might be wrong :)

Comment: According to [this page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data), `fields` is correct as an option for `find()`. I think `select()` is used as a function on a query object.